# SoundPool is loading sounds but every time I play it it says "sample ___ is not ready"?

Tags: android, soundpool

I am having a bit of difficulty with my SoundPool. I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` of my soundIDs located in my `res/raw` folder. I'm creating the SoundPool like so in my ViewHolder class for my RecyclerView:

```
//create the SoundPool
sp = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
//create the AudioManager for managing volume
audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//store the streamVolume in an int
streamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

//set the load listener for my soundfiles
sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
});
```

I am playing the sound on the click of an ImageView like so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(cardImg)) {
        sp.load(context, cardData.getSoundId(), 1);
        if (loaded) {
            sp.play(cardData.getSoundId(), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

And every time I click on the `cardImg` it gives me this error:

```
W/SoundPool﹕ sample 2130968609 not READY
```

Where the sample int changes depending on which card I click, like it should.

So I know that it's GETTING the proper soundID from my ArrayList (stored in `CardData` class), and it definitely sees that it's loaded, because it wouldn't try to play otherwise because `loaded` would never be true. My question is: Why are my sounds never ready?

My sounds are `.m4a` format which Android says is supported in the documentation. I've tried on an Android 5.0 device and an Android 4.4 device but nothing changes.

I have tried using a `MediaPlayer` but I am running into memory errors as I have many short clips that need to be able to be spammed and I read that a SoundPool was a much better way to manage this (?).

Any help would be appreciated! I am super vexxed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong id. `SoundPool.load` returns an id that is suppose to be passed in to `SoundPool.play`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something super simple. I just set an int to my sp.load and passed that int to sp.play :-) Thanks again! I'll accept your answer when I can.